# Detect when a dragged item is dragged out of the window. document.ondragleave()?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, addeventlistener, drag-event

I'm trying to detect when a HTML element is dragged out of the document and off of the window. However, the `dragleave` event bubbles up, so `document.documentElement.ondragleave` gets triggered with every element that the drag leaves in its path to the edge of the page. It also appears that the last element that triggers `dragleave` is the sub element that borders the page, and not the `document` itself.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

By contrast, `mouseleave`

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {console.log(e)})
```

works great and does exactly what I need.

but

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('dragleave', (e) => {console.log(e)})
```

gets triggered for every sub-element… and never triggers for the `documentElement` itself.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`document.addEventListener('dragleave', (e) => {console.log(e)})`